# Bucket group column to show zero values

Tags: lightning, reporting

I am creating a report in lightning and I am using bucketed fields to group rows/columns.

In my situation, I want to show record count as 0 when buckets don't have any matching values in my report.

What I mean is,
As you can see I have 3 buckets and also 'Other'.

[image]

When I use buckets in my report, those don't show up, which is, well, expected since there are no 'bucket_val3' or 'Other' values in my current report.

[image]

Is there a way to show all those four bucket values when trying to use the bucket field as group columns like below?

```
bucket_val1 | bucket_val2 | bucket_val3 | Other | Subtotal
    100     |     25      |      0      |   0   |   125
```